# jquery fadein() with movement

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

The following is the code that control two layers which are textlayer and text. After textlayer display then the text display,

```
<div id="textlayer" style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:#FFFFFF;filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:0.8; position:absolute;left:250;top:150;display:none;">
    <div id="text" style="display:none; padding-top:300px">
    </div>
</div>

    function div2() {
        for (i=0;i<displaymax;i++) {
        $('#span'+i).fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('#textlayer').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $('#text').fadeIn(3000);
        });
    }
```

but i want that the text $('#text') fadein with movement that is from bottom to the top, how do i add the animation to the above code?

Comment: Chain .animate({"top": "+=50px"}) to your #text fadeIn, or get rid of the fadeIn and just use animate to move the element and change the opacity. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: must it be bottom to top? what about top to bottom?

Comment: updated. i changed to use $('#text').animate({"padding-top": "-=50px"}).fadeIn(3000); but not work

Comment: You might clarify exactly what you are looking for.  The question is a little hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the effect you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/5agg2/

Without the colors, of course.  It fades in the main div, then fades and moves from bottom to top the text div.

### Script

```
$('#textlayer').fadeIn('slow', function () {
   $('#text').animate({'opacity': 'show', 'paddingTop': 0}, 2000);
});
```

### Markup

```
<div id="textlayer" style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color:#00FFFF;filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:0.8;position:absolute;left:250;top:150;display:none;overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="text" style="display:none; background-color:Red; padding-top:900px">
        Test Text
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**: I added `padding-top:900px` to the markup for the text div to move it outside of the containing div and I also added `overflow:hidden;` to the container.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of fadeIn, just use animate

```
$('#text').animate({'opacity': 'show', 'paddingTop': 0});
```